# Problema com um vetor de Char em Java

Tags: java

Bom dia!
Fiz um código para ler um char que pode ser numero ou uma letra do teclado. É bem simples e esta rodando, porém fiz um inteiro n para o tamanho do vetor e coloquei o for para i<vetor.length, assim o i vai de 0 até o tamanho do vetor. No caso eu digito 3 para n e o vetor esta com 4 elementos. Neste caso eu inicio o i com 1, porém da erro pois ele leu o primeiro char fora do for. Alguém poderia me mostrar onde estou errando?

A próxima fase do programa é colocar um while e sair do programa quando alguém digitar a tecla 'esc', ainda estou pesquisando como usar o padrão teclado asc, se alguém tiver alguma sugestão, agradeço.

Segue o cógigo:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Digite a quantidade de teclas: ");
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    char[] teclaon = new char[n];   
    int sum1 = 0;
    int sum2 = 0;
    
    System.out.print("Digite uma tecla: ");
    char tecla = sc.next().charAt(0);
            
    for (int i=0; i<teclaon.length; i++) {
        if (tecla == '0' || tecla =='1' || tecla =='2' || tecla =='3' || tecla =='4' || tecla =='5' 
         || tecla=='6' || tecla =='7' || tecla =='8' || tecla =='9' ){
                
            System.out.println("Você digitou um numero!");
            teclaon[i] = tecla;
            sum1++;
            System.out.print("Digite uma tecla: ");
            tecla = sc.next().charAt(0);
        }  
        else {
            System.out.println("Voce digitou uma letra!");
            teclaon[i] = tecla;
            sum2++;
            System.out.print("Digite uma tecla: ");
            tecla = sc.next().charAt(0);
        }
    }
        
    System.out.print("Teclas digitadas: [ ");
    for (char z : teclaon) {
        System.out.print(z + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("]");
    
    System.out.println("Total de numeros = " + sum1);
    System.out.print("Total de letras = " + sum2);
    
    sc.close();
```

Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Não sei se entendi qual é o problema, mas enfim, talvez ajude: https://ideone.com/6IKBTa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você tem que jogar a atribuição para o valor recebido pelo scanner para fora dos condicionais. Assim:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Teste{
        public static void main(String args[]){
                Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
                System.out.print("Digite a quantidade de teclas: ");
                int n = sc.nextInt();
                char[] teclaon = new char[n];
                int sum1 = 0;
                int sum2 = 0;

                for (int i=0; i<teclaon.length; i++) {
                        System.out.print("Digite uma tecla: ");
                        char tecla = sc.next().charAt(0);
                        if (tecla == '0' || tecla =='1' || tecla =='2' || tecla =='3' || tecla =='4' || tecla =='5'
                         || tecla=='6' || tecla =='7' || tecla =='8' || tecla =='9' ){

                            System.out.println("Você digitou um numero!");
                            teclaon[i] = tecla;
                            sum1++;
                        }
                        else {
                            System.out.println("Voce digitou uma letra!");
                            teclaon[i] = tecla;
                            sum2++;
                        }
                }

                System.out.print("Teclas digitadas: [ ");
                for (char z : teclaon) {
                        System.out.print(z + " ");
                }
                System.out.println("]");

                System.out.println("Total de numeros = " + sum1);
                System.out.print("Total de letras = " + sum2);

                sc.close();
        }
}
```

Comment: Perfeito amigo, um detalhe sutil, as vezes a gente não enxerga! Muito obrigado!!